# How to create a thread dump for a running keycloak container

Tags: keycloak, thread-dump

We are running Keycloak 21.1.1 as a container.
Now I want to take a thread dump for that running container.
For another java based container it works to send a signal and the container writes the dump to the console.

```
docker kill --signal=SIGQUIT $container_id
```

but it don't seems to work for a Keycloak container. No dump was print to the docker logs.

As the Keycloak containers are build light weight there are no jstack, jsp, ps ... commands available within the container.

Does someone know how a thread dump could be taken for a Keycloak container without trying to open a debug port in the jvm?

The base image is quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.1.1
"java --version" inside the container prints:

> openjdk 17.0.7 2023-04-18 LTS OpenJDK Runtime

> Environment (Red_Hat-17.0.7.0.7-1.el9_1) (build 17.0.7+7-LTS) OpenJDK

> 64-Bit Server VM (Red_Hat-17.0.7.0.7-1.el9_1) (build 17.0.7+7-LTS, mixed mode)